# Blocking remaining light from bedroom curtains

Tags: light, bedroom, blinds

How can I block the light that gets through the outskirts of my bedroom curtains?
See image below.

Note I am renting in an apartment so I can't do anything permanent.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions I've had success with: Get some painters tape, so it won't leave adhesive on the windows, and put a strip or two on all sides of the the window glass to darken that area and keep light from entering. The other one is to get some white masking/duct tape and add a strip on both sides of the shade to extend the size of the shade by 1/2" to 1" +- on each side. If you don't open the shade, you can also put a strip across the top when the shade's pulled down.

Comment: In my experience, painter’s tape will leave residue or even remove paint if left on long enough.

Comment: @TimB  Good points. That's why I said to put it on the glass. Any residue on the glass will easily scrape off with a single edge razor blade.

Answer (score 1):

Get or make a wooden frame that fits snugly in the window opening. Staple to it corrugated cardboard or other opaque material cut to fit. This layer may be painted or covered with a layer of decorative cloth. Attach knobs or handles for easy installation and removal. If the window is large, use two frames hinged together.

Comment: Yup, that blind's going to be a good 2" off the window itself, so anything you do to mask the glass is not going to be very effective.